# Google DFA (DoubleClick for Advertisers) APIs v1.20

Tags: php, soap, google-api-php-client

As in the subject, I'm working with the Google DFA (DoubleClick for Advertisers) APIs v1.20 and I'm trying to get the list of all my Advertisers.

I didn't found any client library for PHP and DFA APIs v1.20.

The connection is established by SOAP, as requested by Google API docs (https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/docs/getting_started)

The authentication process seems to work correctly but the list request return the following error:

```
WSDoAllReceiver: security processing failed; nested exception is: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: General security error (WSSecurityEngine: Callback supplied no password for: MyUsername)
```

To build the header I'm using the following code

```
$advertiserService  = new SoapClient($advertiserWsdl, $options);

// Set headers.
$headers        = array(DfaHeadersUtil::createWsseHeader($username, $authToken),
                        DfaHeadersUtil::createRequestHeader($namespace, $applicationName));
```

Where the DfaHeadersUtil is a class into the file DfaHeadersUtil.php provided by Google as "header creator".

Is there anybody could help me with this?

Thank you in advance,

Mauro

Comment: You don't need to write the tags in the title. I removed it ;-)

Comment: I didn't know, thank you ^_^'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

The problem was given by not sufficient permissions assigned by the admin to my user..
Easy solution that made me waste half week.. :(

What I learnt:
Occam's razor: "the simplest explanation is usually the correct one"..
Next time.. check the permissions :)

Thank you